# Mass assignment, User vs admin, updating a record the right way?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have removed an element from the mass assignment array.

`protected $guarded = ['id', 'status', 'org', 'params', 'last_visited_date'];`

Because admin users need to be able to update the user model/record.

However now a user could pass through the element in a form and overwrite a field, this is undesirable.

What's the best way to tackle mass assignment on the mentioned user model?

Hopefully i dont have to have 2 user models?

Comment: Try the `$fillable` instead of guarded and specify the elements that are mass assignable.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like i can just manually input

```
    $input = $request->all();
    $user->activation = $input['activation'];
    $user->save();
```